# Increment reference cell by a week

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a field starting at B3 that is e.g. "28/11/2016" and every field beside it needs to be incremented to be a week after that.

Currently, I am doing this manually, i.e. `=B3+7` then `=B3+14` and so on.

I'm quite inexperienced with Google Sheets and can't find a format tool that will help me do this. Ideally, I would need to have a formula that will take the cell before and add a week onto it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So what you can do is B3 => `=DATE(2016,11,28)` and B4 => `B3+7` and then select B4 and drag through bottom you will have dates in increment of weeks.

Here is the link that I did the same thing : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NGOAYY2gXkNKDbz4Ang2NYK9Z9RoROXC3qDrmfoeMog/edit#gid=0

Comment: Ah of course! Lack of coffee has resulted in this question.  Thank you Harshil